# How to remove duplicate value among columns irresppective of their order in python or pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a dataframe in which i have duplicate value among columns. I want to remove only those values from the dataframe that are common for all the columns

INPUT DATAFRAME:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
|    A     |    B      |   C        |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|  Food    |   Chill   |  Traveller |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|  Chill   |   Food    |  Chill     |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| Traveller|   Glamour |  Glamour   |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|  Novel   | Traveller |   Party    |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|  Pub     |   Party   |  Driving   |
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

OUTPUT DATAFRAME:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
|    A     |    B      |   C        |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|  Food    |   Party   |  Driving   |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|  Novel   |   Food    |    Party   |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|   Pub    |   Glamour |  Glamour   |
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

Is there any effective way to do this in python or pyspark?

Comment: Would be nice if you included code to instantiate the dataframe, such that we don't have to type it in when demonstrating the solution.

Comment: It can be done, but this isn't really a good use for a spark dataframe. It seems like you'd be better off with one dataframe per column. What is it that you're trying to do? There may be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a "dataframe" refers to a data structure that takes the form of an array in which there is some relationship across columns, and another relationship across rows. Here, there doesn't seem to be a relationship across a row: "Food", "Party", and "Driving", for instance, aren't connected to each other. So the :dataframe" concept is of limited applicability. You can create a dictionary of lists like this:

```
common = [item for item in df['A'].values if all(item in df[col_name].values for col_name in df.columns)]
unique_elements = {col_name:[item for item in df[col_name].values if not item in common] for col_name in df.columns}
```

If you really want to, you can create a dataframe out of `unique_elements`.

Note that there are also solutions with the `set` datatype, but that would eliminate multiplicities (it's not clear what you want with respect to that).

Answer (score 0):

Can use `set intersection` and `aggregate`

```
>>> tr = set(df.A.values) & set(df.B.values) & set(df.C.values)
>>> df[~df.isin(tr)].agg(lambda s: s[~pd.isnull(s)].values)

    A       B       C
0   Food    Food    Glamour
1   Novel   Glamour Party
2   Pub     Party   Driving
```